# angular 2 date pipe format not rendering as expected

Tags: date, angular, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to display the day of the week with the 12h time.

Sun 8:00 PM

This seems like a great task for the date pipe

```
{{myDate | date:'EEEE jm'}}
```

what gets displayed is

Sunday 8 PM0

the documentation for the pipe states that 
'shortTime': equivalent to 'jm' (e.g. 12:05 PM for en-US)

basically I want the shortTime output with the weekday include.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really strange behaviour, `{{myDate | date:'EEE jm'}}` should work like a charm, I think it is Angular 2 bug. Until they fix that, you can use this as an temporary solution:

`{{myDate | date:'EEE'}} {{myDate | date:'jm'}}`

It displays date the way you want it, just tested it.